# how to set height and width of Bitmap image ?

Tags: android

Good morning,
I hava a question. In my application I'm trying to load a BitMap image. As the guide of Android suggest (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) I use the method

`decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,int reqWidth, int reqHeight)`

It's work perfectly, but At first no because i set reqWidth and reqHeight according to the dimension of my smartphone (height: 2560; width: 1440). For this the app produced the follow error:

> 12-16 12:21:51.911 5401-6627/? E/ACRA: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 44236812 byte allocation with 13002080 free bytes and 12MB until OOM
>   12-16 12:21:51.911 5401-6627/? E/ACRA:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) etc....

But when i change height and width, as the guide suggest (100 x 100) it work and after I increased this to 500 x 500. For this, my question is **how to set this value dinamically for different device ? OR this value can be left static and consequently it's adapt to the size screen ?**

Sorry for my bad English I am italian.
I hope I have been clear ! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you may need is Android's feature that uses different drawable resources depending on user's screen. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

In your case, you will manually create pictures of different sizes and put them accordingly into different folders inside `res`. After that Android system will handle the selection of the right image based on the device.

Comment: mmm I don't understand very well, my image hava alredy the different sizes, for example: 

image2.jpg
     image2.jpg (hdpi)
      image2.jpg (ldpi)
     image2.jpg (mdpi)
     image2.jpg (xdpi)
Do you refer at this ?

Comment: Let's say you have a 100x100px image and you want to use it as a drawable. You put it under the name `my_drawable.png` inside `drawable-mdpi` folder in you `res`. Then you create an image that is 75x75px and put it in `drawable-ldpi` under the same name `my_drawable.png`. Then you create the same image that is 150x150px and put it in the `drawable-hdpi` folder as `my_drawable.png` and so on until you have a picture that matches every screen density you would like to work with

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use volley library for better Experience, check out the link :
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Answer (score 0):

try with this code with xml file

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/img"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
/>
```

programmatically you can set size of image

```
  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_avatar);
  img.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
  img.getLayoutParams().width = 150;
```

Comment: It work but i would the width and height as match_parent andimg.getLayoutParams().height = 200; move my image into upper left :(

Comment: @AntonioFaienza   this is depends on you where you are write your image in (container) Layout you need to give margin from top or bottom,left,right etc to set your image with your way